# How to use Grails session for login

Tags: postgresql, session, grails

I am messing around making an app in grails. At this point I have already made a login view and the controller. How its working is I got a service which queries my db for the credentials and then if they are valid proceeds to the main screen as shown below. Now I need to add a session to it so that you cant bypass the login. Keep in mind I got no Domain classes because all I need Im querying the database.

This is how the controller works rn:

[image]

The login service is basically a firstrow query.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't clear what you really need but in your controller is a variable named `session` which you can interact with as a `Map` and do things like `session.isLoggedIn = true` or `if(session.isLoggedIn) { ... }` etc.  You probably shouldn't do that sort of thing in your app though.  You should consider something like https://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/.

Comment: Basically, after the query to the database in the controller I need to somehow make a session for the user for him to access the main page. I don't wanna mess with spring security just yet. I know its easier, but I wanna learn the fundamentals for starters

Comment: "Basically, after the query to the database in the controller I need to somehow make a session for the user for him to access the main page." - You don't need to make a session.  It is there for you.  The `session` property in your controller points to the session.  You can put whatever you like in the session, including a flag indicating whether the user is logged in, or whatever else you like.

Comment: There is a whole lot to building an authorization and authentication system and there will be a number of pieces.  You are likely to want to do a good bit of the work in an interceptor (or a filter if you are using Grails 2).